# Embed U(5) to U(16) by specifying the 16-dimensional complex representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, young-tableaux

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$

My question concerns all the possible ways to embed SU(5) to U(16) by specifying the 16-dimensional complex representation, denoted as ${\bf 16}$ in U(16). (The ${\bf 16}$ is also a box in Young tableau as the fundamental representation of U(16).)

### Warm up

For example, if we consider the embedding:
$$
\U(16)\supset \Spin(10) \supset  \SU(5),
$$
then there are at least two ways of embedding:
$$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$, decomposed as
$  \mathbf 1 \oplus \overline{\mathbf 5} \oplus \mathbf{10} $ in $\SU(5).$
}$$
$$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$, decomposed as
$\mathbf 1 \oplus {\mathbf 5} \oplus \overline{\mathbf{10}} $ in $\SU(5).$
}$$

### Question

Now consider the embedding:
$$
\U(16)\supset  \SU(5)
$$
via specifying
$$
\text{Representation ${\bf 16}$ of U(16) is decomposed as the representation ? of SU(5).}
$$
What are the possible ways of embeddings and decompositions?

Since the dimension of representation of SU(5) smaller than 16-dimensional ${\bf 16}$ involves
${\mathbf 1}$, $\mathbf{5}$, $\mathbf{10}$, $\mathbf{15}$, and
$\overline{\mathbf{5}}$, $\overline{\mathbf{10}}$, $\overline{\mathbf{15}}$.

For example, do we have new  embedding via new decompositions:
$$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$  decomposed as
$\mathbf 1 \oplus {\mathbf 5} \oplus {\mathbf{10}} $ in $\SU(5)?$
}$$
$$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$  decomposed as
$\mathbf 1 \oplus \overline{\mathbf 5} \oplus \overline{\mathbf{10}} $ in $\SU(5)?$
}$$

Are all the combinatory allowed? for example
$$\text{$\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$  decomposed as
$a \mathbf{1} \oplus b {\mathbf 5} \oplus
c \overline{\mathbf 5} \oplus d \mathbf{10}
\oplus e \overline{\mathbf{10}} \oplus f \mathbf{15}
\oplus g \overline{\mathbf{15}}  $ in $\SU(5)?$
}$$
What are the constraints on $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ other than $$a+5b+5c+10d+10e+15f+15g=16?$$
Other constraints?